# Filtering Pandas dataframe on two criteria where one column is a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a `Pandas` `Dataframe` with columns `Project Type` and `Parts`. I would like to know how many part As are used in projects of Project Type 1. I am trying to use `.count()`, but it doesn't return just a single number.

```
import pandas as pd
parts_df = pd.DataFrame(data = [['Type 1', ['A', 'B']], ['Type 2', ['B']]], columns=['Project Type', 'Parts'])
print (parts_df[(parts_df['Project Type'] == 'Type 1') & ('A' in parts_df['Parts'])]).count()
```

Output:

```
Project Type    0
Parts           0
dtype: int64
```

Desired Output:

```
1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try something like this :

```
sum(['A' in i for i in parts_df[parts_df['Project Type']=='Type 1']['Parts'].tolist()])
```

sample :

```
In[32]: parts_df = pd.DataFrame(data = [['Type 1', ['A', 'B']], ['Type 2', ['A']], ['Type 1', ['C']]], columns=['Project Type', 'Parts'])
In[33]: sum(['A' in i for i in parts_df[parts_df['Project Type']=='Type 1']['Parts'].tolist()])
Out[33]: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you want the following:

```
In [13]:
parts_df.loc[parts_df['Project Type'] == 'Type 1','Parts'].apply(lambda x: x.count('A'))

Out[13]:
0    1
Name: Parts, dtype: int64
```

If you want the scalar value rather than a series then you can call `.values` attribute and index into the np array:

```
In [15]:
parts_df.loc[parts_df['Project Type'] == 'Type 1','Parts'].apply(lambda x: x.count('A')).values[0]

Out[15]:
1
```

You could just add a column that counts the 'A' parts:

```
In [17]:
parts_df['A count'] = parts_df['Parts'].apply(lambda x: x.count('A'))
parts_df
Out[17]:
  Project Type   Parts  A count
0       Type 1  [A, B]        1
1       Type 2     [B]        0
```

you can then filter:

```
In [18]:    
parts_df[(parts_df['Project Type'] == 'Type 1') & (parts_df['A count'] > 0)]

Out[18]:
  Project Type   Parts  A count
0       Type 1  [A, B]        1
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `'A' in df['Parts']` to a lambda.

```
import pandas as pd
parts_df = pd.DataFrame(data = [['Type 1', ['A', 'B']], ['Type 2', ['B']]], columns=['Project Type', 'Parts'])
res = (parts_df[(parts_df['Project Type'] == 'Type 1') & (parts_df['Parts'].apply(lambda x: 'A' in x))]).count()
res.max()
```

Result:

```
1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can spend a second to re-format the columns, and make life a little easier:

```
parts_df.Parts = parts_df.Parts.map(lambda x: ' '.join(x))
#  Project type Parts
#0       Type 1   A B
#1       Type 2     B
```

Now you can use the [`Series.str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) method:

```
dummies = parts_df.Parts.str.get_dummies( sep=' ')
#   A  B
#0  1  1
#1  0  1
```

which shows the presence or absence of each "Part" using either a 1 or 0 respectively.  Use this dummies frame to create a dataframe that can easily be manipulated using all of the standard pandas methods (pandas doesn't like lists in columns):

```
new_parts_df = pandas.concat( (parts_df['Project Type'], dummies), axis=1)
#  Project type  A  B
#0       Type 1  1  1
#1       Type 2  0  1
```

You can now easily count groups in several ways. The most efficient thing to do would be use [`pandas.DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html), but the unfortunate white space in your column name `"Project Type"` makes this difficult. I would avoid white spaces in column names whenever possible. Try this:

```
new_parts_df.rename( columns={'Project Type': 'Project_Type'}, inplace=True)
print(len(new_parts_df.query( 'Project_Type=="Type 1" and A==1')))
# 1
```